# It felt like "I'm going on an adventure"

Tags: word-choice

I have been working on a software that it looks like an adventure (it's hard).

In the last three weeks, I have worked on new software, and I finished it just now. I want to say to my co-workers "working on TICKET-X was a real adventure. It felt like: https://giphy.com/gifs/running-adventure-movie-HVr4gFHYIqeti.

Can I use the sentence *It felt like*?

Comment: Going **on** an adventure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"It felt like" is not a sentence. If we take the caption of that gif to be the rest of the sentence, and assume that you would put it in quote marks, then you get:

> It felt like "I'm going on an adventure"

This isn't something that should be used in formal language; think feeling like a bit of quoted dialogue isn't good formal English. Rendering the same idea in formal English might look like:

> It felt like I was going on an adventure.

Alternatively, to keep the reference from the gif, it might be:

> I felt like Bilbo setting out in *An Unexpected Journey*, saying "I'm going on an adventure".

However, in casual, informal English, there's no actual problem with:

> It felt like "I'm going on an adventure"

You might even expand it, assuming we're talking about speaking aloud here rather than text (with the ability to link in the gif):

> It felt like "I'm going on an adventure", like Bilbo, you know?

In any case, "it felt like" is a perfectly reasonable way to say this.